# Add Hotwire to existing Rails 6.1 app using sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

I'm trying to upgrade an existing Rails 6.1 with sprockets app to use stimulus. I installed

```
gem 'importmap-rails'
gem 'hotwire-rails'
```

The `javascript_importmap_tags` causes this error in Firefox Developer Tools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “application”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
```

Should this work alongside sprockets?
I have `importmap-rails (0.7.6)`, `stimulus-rails (0.4.2)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error can safely be ignored, it doesn't cause any issues.